# Best way to programatically add "rel" attributes to page and post images

Tags: functions, images, filters, attachments, single

For single posts and pages, I would like to add certain `rel` attributes to all the images on the contained therein added with the "Add Image" functionality on the edit screen.

The attribute would be `rel="lightbox[post id]"`

What function would I filter to accomplish this most effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**image_send_to_editor**

```
function insert_img_rel_attrib( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt )
{
  /* Run your magic on the image $html to insert rel attrib */
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'insert_img_rel_attrib' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rel="whatever"` attribute is only for search engines. If you consider to make your content "better" for spiders, crawlers and such, [take a look at this list first](http://de.selfhtml.org/html/kopfdaten/beziehungen.htm).

Comment: @kaiser: nope. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel - semantically fine for relating a lightbox gallery of images.

Comment: @two7s_clash: Jes, take a look at the link behind the link to provided: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links

Comment: @kaiser: I see "Authors may wish to define additional link types not described in this specification." I'll be sure to add my usage in a profile. :) FYI, this is a quite common, practical, and working useage of rel tags. I invite you to find real word examples of some of these "recognized link types." At the end of the day, these are just recommendations and to say that the `rel` attribute is only for search engines is just plain wrong.

Comment: "Wrong" is a pretty harsh term in this context. Aside from `canonical` and `nofollow` nothing is official, but I'd stick to those terms that are most common: next, prev, last, first, attachment, up, top, etc.

Comment: @kaiser: Sorry, not meaning to be harsh. I just don't understand for what real world reason you would advocate just sticking to those terms?

Comment: @two7s_clash: n/p. I normally try to write code that i hope will still work in a year or more. The more often you stumble upon one of those terms, the more common they seem. So I stick with the normal "link" rel-s (that don't belong to relationships like "friend", "co-worker" and such) that belong to non-specific navigation ("first", "last", "next", etc) in the hope that they will be used by SEs in the future (which they likely will).